# Silverlight 4 screen capture function

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I am wondering whether Silverlight 4 is able to capture screen as image or capture screen operations as video? Or both? Is there an online Demo to experience the effect?

I am using C# + .Net 4.0 + VS2010 + ASP.Net + III 7.5.

Comment: I hope not, it would be a major security hole unless the captured region was restricted to the silverlight app.

Comment: Thanks, you said "hope not", you mean for which feature, capture as image or capture as video?

Comment: both, either one would allow a web page steal information from other windows.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an online Demo to show capture screen operations as video function? I Google hard but can not find one. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it. There is an [article](http://www.uzmaninasor.com/?p=314) posted about this.

This article is written in Turkish. Try to find `CaptureSource` part, the code is located just below it. Ask me for translation or any question.

Comment: Well... Any English based samples. :-)

Comment: @Serkan Hekimoglu, you reversed the link text and url.

Comment: Used chrome to translate, this answer deals with image capture from a camera, definately not what the OP wants.

Comment: I am wondering whether Silverlight 4 is able to capture screen as image or capture screen operations as video? Or both? This article shows how capture image. And user asks this too.

Comment: @Serkan Hekimoglu, perhaps it got lost in the automated translation, but that article seems focused purely on webcam capture.  The OP wants to be able to capture from the screen, for example: A video of someone drawing a picture in MS Paint.

Comment: Ok. There should be some misunderstanding. Sorry for the answer.

Comment: No problem, question answered!